# Count repeated elements in Java without using loops or imports

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion

For training purposes I tried to code a program which counts how often a given number appears in an given array of integers. Then checks if the number is even or odd. Without using any imports or loops. I tried to solve it recursive.
For Example:

```
(3, new int[]{3,3,4,5,3,3,2,1})
```

There are 4 threes, so the Program should check if 4 is even or odd.

After days of coding and not working code I decided to ask here:
any Solutions?

```
public static int evenNumberOf(int num, int[] numarr) {

int i = 0 ;
        int counter = 0;
        if(a == null || a.length == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if(a[i] == a.length -1 ) {
                if(counter % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                    return true;
                    
                } else System.out.println("false");
                    return false;
                
            } else {
            if(a[i] == n) {
                counter++;
                i++;
                return evenNumberOf(n,a) ;
            } else {
                i++;
                return evenNumberOf(n,a) ;
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've written, so we can try and help figure out what you've gotten wrong?

Comment: Sorry, i will do that!

Comment: Please post your complete code. Where are `a` and `n` declared? How do you return `true` when your function says it returns `int`? What do you mean by "not working"? But your problem seems to be that you start searching at the start of the array every time you call your function.

Comment: How can you `return false` or `return true`  in a method that should return int ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If you are trying to do this recursively, you can do this quickly with divide and conquer. Split the array into half, count each subarray and combine the results. Make sure the base case of an empty array/single element array is handled correctly.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood, but I think op wants to count the repetitions of just the given number (`3` in the example) which can be done recursively very easily.

Comment: Ah I see, that would be a much easier task. I misunderstood as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the misunderstanding. I often cant express what i watn to say in english.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(evenNumberOf(2, 0, new int[]{2,0,3,7,6,11,1,2}, 0));
}

//arr should not be empty, index and count >= 0
public static int evenNumberOf(int num, int index,int[]numarr, int count) {
    if(index >= numarr.length) return count;
    if(numarr[index] == num ) {
        count++;
    }
    return evenNumberOf(num, ++index, numarr, count);
}
```

You can add an helper method to make calling simpler :

```
public static int evenNumberOf(int num, int[] numarr) {
    return evenNumberOf(num, 0, numarr,0);
}
```